# Override test settings from a file

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-settings

For context, when one wants to change settings in a test ([yes, it's ok to change it there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48042132/5675325)), we can use [override_settings()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings) or [modify_settings()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.modify_settings) (as [observed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42905759/5675325)). [That works when running the tests in parallel too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69752186/5675325).

Generally speaking, I do something like this

```
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings

@override_settings(LOGIN_URL='/other/login/')
class LoginTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_login(self):
        response = self.client.get('/sekrit/')
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/other/login/?next=/sekrit/')
```

Thing is, the list of settings can get big. So would to get the key-values from another file.

How to override from a file instead of having a long list like `LOGIN_URL='/other/login/', ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not file config, but you can use ** to pass dict as kwargs to decorator:

```
from .TEST_CONF import EXAMPLE_CONF

@override_settings(**EXAMPLE_CONF)
class TestExample(TestCase):
    def test_sth(self):
        from django.conf import settings
        self.fail('{} {} {}'.format(settings.A, settings.B, settings.CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER))
```

and TEST_CONF file looks like this:

```
EXAMPLE_CONF = {
    'CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER': True,
    'A': 'sth',
    'B': 'else',
}
```

result of this fail is:

```
AssertionError: sth else True
```